Energy balance approach to understanding pool water total evaporation
I had a thought and I'm looking for affirmation and/or additional understanding.
Introduction
I'm working on a project where I'd like to understand how much water should be expected to evaporate from a still body of water - in my case, a 200,000 gallon (757,000 kg of water) neighborhood pool, with 443 m2 surface area.
I thought about it and realized that despite ongoing solar heating, pool water temperature does not rise without bound. Instead, at 1-year intervals, the water temperature is roughly the same. For instance, the water temperature is roughly the same every March 1st.
Hypothesis
All the energy that goes into the water will end up coming back out. Over a long time frame, energy in = energy out.
Energy Input Analysis
My understanding (which may be wrong) is that by far the dominant energy source for pool water is sunlight. I believe that Global Horizontal Irradiance (GHI) (historic actuals available from the National Solar Radiation Database) is the measure of solar energy hitting the pool. Then the pool has an energy absorption profile, based on the water depth and the albedo of the pool bottom. It appears to me that a ~5' deep pool will absorb about 65% of the GHI that it receives.
In my case, based on the NSRDB data and assuming the 65% absorption ratio, I figure our pool absorbs 523k kWh per year (or an average of 135 W/m2).
Energy Output Analysis
Energy release should equal energy absorption. I expect the vast bulk of energy release will be from evaporating water. The water energy of vaporization at 82°F (roughly our pool's annual average temperature) is 2435 Joules/gram.
If all that energy evaporates water, then we're evaporating 774,000 kg or about 204,000 gallons of water per year.
Questions
Does that logic seem sound? Are there other meaningful sources or sinks of energy here?
Based on this analysis, I have a follow-up question: If we install an evaporative cooling tower to reduce peak summer water temperatures, would it noticeably increase the total annual water evaporation? My hypothesis is that it would not, as it would merely shift the timing of evaporation within the annual cycle. Am I overlooking any meaningful factors in this conclusion?

you have left out radiation to space at night, which is basically the reverse of solar radiation, and convection heat transfer from wind.  My guess is ambient temperature has more of an effect than sunlight.

Concrete pools (shotcrete) sweat, and this is determined by the soil surrounding the pool. It could be significant. Wind promotes evaporation, while ambient humidity inhibits it. Evaporation is influenced by the surrounding landscaping and hardscaping.

A google search can be very effective... See https://www.lathampool.com/blog/maintain/help-my-pool-is-leaking-or-is-it/#:~:text=What%20is%20the%20normal%20evaporation,the%20pool's%20total%20surface%20area. or https://www.angi.com/articles/pool-level-dropping-it-leak-or-evaporation.htm

@SolarMike I don't appreciate the shade that I didn't search before asking the question. Those links don't help because they don't address the energy balance question.

@TigerGuy can you elaborate on why you feel that irradiation and convection would be material heat sinks? My gut says they'd be small compared to evaporation but I'd like to learn more.

@TigerGuy I asked a chatbot about factoring in irradiation and it gave me the following formula:
P_net = εσ(T1^4 - T2^4)
ε = water emissivity = 0.96
σ = Stefan-Boltzmann constant = 5.67E-8
T1 and T2 = the temperatures of the bodies in Kelvin
Applying that to my pool and weather data, I calculate an average energy emission of 31.5 Watts per square meter, or 23% of the total absorbed GHI (I'm a little surprised). That would materially reduce the evaporation needed to maintain energy balance. Do you think that's a reasonable application of the concept and a realistic result?
